# Why do sda5 uses so much disk space?

Tags: hard-disk

On Linux Mint, how should I free some space? I got an error "The volume "Filesystem root" has only 0 bytes of disk space remaining. I have

```
df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             800712      1696    799016   1% /run
/dev/sda5      122379888 122363568         0 100% /
tmpfs            4003544      1532   4002012   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         8      5112   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1          98304     35806     62498  37% /boot/efi
tmpfs             800708       112    800596   1% /run/user/1000

ls /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5
cd /dev/sda5
bash: cd: /dev/sda5: Not a directory
```

Comment: You've used 116 GB on your root (primary) partition, `/`

Comment: Check what's eating up space as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314394/my-hard-disk-is-full-how-can-i-determine-whats-taking-up-space. When you know that you can start moving stuff to another drive to free up space.