# Why is /dev/sda1 being almost full?

Tags: debian, filesystems, disk-usage

I am running a `debian-9-torch-xla-v20200208` image on a Google Cloud Platform VM instance and have a 40GB persistent disk attached to it. I am running out of persistent disk space while downloading files using `wget`.

On running the `df -h` command, I got the following output which shows that `/dev/sda1` is almost full:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   11M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        43G   39G  1.8G  96% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

I cannot figure out what is filling up disk space on `/dev/sda1`. Could you please help me solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you do to try and find what is filling the device? Use the `mount` command to find out all the mount points that use `sda1` and then [use find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/finding-largest-file-recursively) to list large files.

Comment: Used ` mount|find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -1` and found a zip file that is about 4GB in the home directory. But how does that make up about 39GB at /dev/sda1?

Comment: You may want to check more  than just the largest file. Could be a few large files or many smaller files or mix.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @kaylum. Seems there were duplicates in ./.local/share/Trash/files/, which contains binaries that I have been storing in home directory. Any advice on clearing ./.local? I guess unlike ./temp it is not volatile...Thanks again!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/finding-files-that-use-the-most-disk-space provides answers with elegant way to find out what's eating up your disk space